# Why for every range of N numbers, there are always approximately 0.392*N numbers which contains perfect squares as factors?

Tags: probability-distributions, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization, square-numbers

As to my current understanding, when simplifying radicands of roots what we are really doing is checking if this said number contains a perfect square number as a factor. Studying the distribution of those cases I noticed that for every range of N numbers there will always be approximately 0,392 * N numbers that has as one of its factors at least one perfect square. Why is this? This probably has some very obvious "analytical motive" behind and I would appreciate very much to learn which it is. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that the similar question has answer $\dfrac6{\pi^2}\approx0.6079\not\approx0.392$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Could be the "similarity" is only up to $p\mapsto1-p$?

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich, that seems right since $0.6079+0.392\approx1$.  (It took me a moment to realize that your $p$ is probability, not prime)